# rxjs / ngrx / groupby nested values

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx

I am struggling with this for days and could need some help from some more advanced people :).

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ywi4.png)

As you can see on my picture I got the following structure.

I got n tasks in an Observable:

- Tasks[]

  - [0] task id 1

    - [0] jobs[]

      - [0] job 1

        - ...
      - [2] job 3

        - job id 3
        - ...
        - reference id 515

What do I want to do?

I want to group all my tasks by the reference id so I can access my Observable from the html via ionic.

```
private getTasksWithReference()
{
let localTasksWithReference = this._store.select(state => state.tasks)
  .map((localTasks: Task[]) => 
  {
    return localTasks.filter((localTask: Task) =>
    {
      return this.typeCode.toString() === 
 localTask.taskProcessTypeCode.toString();
    })
  });

let test = localTasksWithReference.switchMap(tasks => Observable.from(tasks)
  .groupBy(task => task.taskType)
  .mergeMap(group => group.toArray())
  .toArray()
);

let test2 = localTasksWithReference.switchMap(tasks => tasks.map(task => 
Observable.from(task.jobs)
  .groupBy(job => job.businessTransactionDocumentReference.id)
  .mergeMap(group => group.toArray())
  .toArray()
));
```

Test2 is what I want to achieve, but it doesn't give me the expected result. And even if I need to keep the structure posted above and not only the jobs.

If anyone can help it would be a big help :)

Regards,
nosTa

Comment: Could you clarify your expected result? Specifically, are you grouping tasks by the reference id of _one_ of its jobs, all of its jobs, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basis of what I think you need

```
const grouped$ = localTasksWithReference$.reduce( (grouping, task) => {

  // Get all referenceIds for the task
  const referenceIds = task.jobs.reduce( (references, job) => { 
    references.push(job.referenceId);
    return references;
  }, []);

  // Add each referenceId and task to the grouping 
  referenceIds.forEach(referenceId => {
    grouping[referenceId] = grouping[referenceId] || [];
    // Ensure task only grouped once per referenceId
    if (grouping[referenceId].indexOf(task) === -1) {
      grouping[referenceId].push(task);
    }
  })

  return grouping;
}, {});
```

You can see it working and make adjustments here [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/QqRQod)

The output is an observable of an object which has a property for each distinct referenceId, and the property value is an array of the tasks with jobs that have that referenceId.

```
{
  ref#1: [
      {taskId: 1, jobs: Array(3)}
      {taskId: 2, jobs: Array(3)}
    ],
  ref#2: [
      {taskId: 1, jobs: Array(3)}
      {taskId: 2, jobs: Array(3)}
    ]
}
```

You will need to shape this output for appropriate use on the template. If you need help with that, please show the proposed HTML structure.

Note, I've assumed that a task should only appear once per referenceId.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Richard Matsen.

```
let localTasksWithReference = this._store.select(state => state.tasks)
        .map((localTasks: Task[]) => {
            return localTasks.filter((localTask: Task) => {
                return this.typeCode.toString() === localTask.taskProcessTypeCode.toString();
            })
        });

    let referenceGroup = localTasksWithReference.reduce((grouping, tasks: any) => {
        tasks.reduce((test, task) => {
            let referenceIds =
                task.jobs.reduce((references, job) => {
                    references.push(job.businessTransactionDocumentReference.id);
                    return references;
                }, []);

            referenceIds.forEach(referenceId => {
                grouping[referenceId] = grouping[referenceId] || [];
                if (grouping[referenceId].indexOf(task) === -1) {
                    grouping[referenceId].push(task);
                }
            })
        }, []);
        console.log(grouping);
        return grouping;
    }, {});

this.tasksWithReference = referenceGroup;
this.tasksWithReference.subscribe(console.log);
```

[image: Result]

Works like a charm. But I could need indeed some help with the HTML.

What I want to do is the referenceId as the title and the tasks below.

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header *ngFor="let taskWithReference of tasksWithReference | async">
      test
    </ion-list-header>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

I guess we need an Array for that not an object? I am working with ionic here.

This is how my working tasks look like and above are my grouped references.

[image: references]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested there are two ways to solve this:

```
private getTasksWithReferenceOOOOOOOOLD() {
    let localTasksWithReference = this._store.select(state => state.tasks)
        .map((localTasks: Task[]) => {
            return localTasks.filter((localTask: Task) => {
                return this.typeCode.toString() === localTask.taskProcessTypeCode.toString();
            })
        }).reduce((grouping, tasks: any) => {
            grouping = {};
            tasks.reduce((test, task) => {
                let referenceIds =
                    task.jobs.reduce((references, job) => {
                        references.push(job.businessTransactionDocumentReference.id);
                        return references;
                    }, []);


                referenceIds.forEach(referenceId => {
                    grouping[referenceId] = grouping[referenceId] || { "tasks": [] };
                    if (grouping[referenceId].tasks.indexOf(task) === -1) {
                        grouping[referenceId].tasks.push(task);
                    }
                })
            }, []);
            const arr = Object.keys(grouping).reduce((arr, key) =>
                ([...arr, { ...grouping[key], key }]), // Can add key if you don't have it
                []);
            this.tasksWithReference = Observable.of(arr);
            return arr;
        }, {}).subscribe();
}
```

Now I can access the referenceid with the key and the tasks with reference.tasks.

Second Solution:

```
public tasksWithReferenceMap: Map<string, Task[]>

public getTasksWithReference() {
    this.tasksWithReference = this._store.select(state => state.tasks)
        .map((localTasks: Task[]) => {
            this.tasksWithReferenceMap = new Map<string, Task[]>();
            return localTasks.filter((localTask: Task) => {
                return this.typeCode.toString() === localTask.taskProcessTypeCode.toString();
            }).reduce((grouping, task: Task) => {
                // Get all referenceIds for the task
                const referenceIds = task.jobs.reduce((references, job: Job) => {
                    references.push(job.businessTransactionDocumentReference.id);
                    return references;
                }, []);

                // Add each referenceId and task to the grouping 
                referenceIds.forEach(referenceId => {
                    grouping.set(referenceId, grouping.get(referenceId) || []);
                    if (grouping.get(referenceId).indexOf(task) === -1) {
                        grouping.get(referenceId).push(task);
                    }
                })

                return grouping;
            }, this.tasksWithReferenceMap);
        });
}
```

Working with maps here.

Than we have to create a custom pipe:

```
import { Task } from './../../models/task.model';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'keys',
 })
 @Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
 export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform
 {


 transform(value: Map<string, Task[]>, args: string[]): any
  {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key of value.keys())
    {
      keys.push({ key: key });
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and than access the html:

```
 <ion-list *ngFor="let reference of tasksWithReference | async | keys | orderBy: 'key' : reverseReference">
        <ion-list-header class="referenceListHeader">
          {{'REFERENCE' | translate}}: {{reference?.key}}
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let task of tasksWithReferenceMap.get(reference?.key) | orderBy: 'id'; let i = index">
```

Thanks for you help again, otherwise it would have taken some more time ;)